# Identifying duals and second duals in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, and $E$ is a closed subspace of $X^{*}$. Can we find $F$ a closed subspace of $X$ such that $F^{**}$ can be (naturally) identified with $E^{*}$? Does it make a difference if $E$ is finite codimensional in $X^{*}$?

Comment: $F^{**}$ is naturally identified with a subspace of $X^{**}$ while $E^*$ is naturally identified with a _quotient_ of $X^{**}$, namely $X^{**}/E_\perp$. The most one can hope for is to find $F$ such that $F^{**}$ and $E_\perp$ are complementary subspaces of $X^{**}$; would this be natural enough?

Comment: @user4412195 Good point. However there is no reason to expect that $E_\perp$ is complemented in $X^{**}$, so probably that is not possible in general. Perhaps I am asking the wrong question, I will try to rethink it.